# Change field length in drupal unit description

Tags: drupal, size, field, max

I'm having trouble using Drupal Rooms module.
This is when I input a description for unit.
Maximum length of Unit description is said to be 255.
I wanna input longer.
I figured out that those are stored in tables - field_data_unit_description_description and field_revision_unit_description_description.
I altered those tables, changed the length of the field to 2048.
But it still says "the text may not be longer than 255 characters."
I tried to change this value in db manually, but it never changed....
If i change the value in the site, the value in db changes, but if i change the value in db, it's not shown in the site.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself by making a new attribute field for this.
It's quite better way I think since it works well and is fully customizable.
Created a new field in Manage Fields panel, with field attribute : Long Text.
It worked well.